# SQL / Postgres, big table vs multiple tables, how to performance test?

Tags: database, postgresql, testing, schema

I'm working on a Postgres database where I've got some records that will be queried / accessed all the time, and they have a open-ended amount of optional "metadata" what will be collected over time.

To illustrate the idea, consider a case like a national car dealership network. You could have a table like:

```
Vehicles
--------
id
type
status
location
```

That information is all required and needed in just almost every query. But there's a bunch of optional extra information like make, model, year, mileage, color, previous owner, MSRP, blue book value, etc etc.

Those could all just be fields on the Vehicles table, or they could be fields in a different table like `VehicleMetadata`, with a foreign key pointing to the specific vehicle.

As a SQL layman, I don't really know what difference doing this in one table or two tables will make. I'd be interested to understand:

1. As a db guru, how would you compare and test these different schema options and determine which performs best?
2. Is one approach or the other generally considered more conventional or standard practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Get your database normalization right, at least 3NF, and you will be fine. You don't have enough cars to get a performance problem...

Comment: @FrankHeikens probably has basically the right answer, I've expanded quite a bit on that in the form of an answer below -- but there's no disagreement with Frank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for background reading that's extremely relevant to your question, see [this link on database normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm).

Let me simplify and say that whether you store all of the data together, or in separate tables, boils down to a tradeoff of query performance to data redundancy.  I can't tell you what you should do because I don't know your query load, but here's how to think of it.

**Tradeoff between redundancy and query performance**

You have all of these extra optional fields, like make ("Honda").  If you store `make=Honda` in every car record, you're going to be storing Honda many thousands or millions of times, because Hondas are really popular.  If on the other hand you split `make` out into a separate table, you can store `Honda` once and refer to it by primary/foreign key.  You can also attach other data to that Honda value.   So if you do it as a separate table, every time you need that Honda "fact", you'll have to do a join.  Relational databases are good at joins, but they're still slower than storing the data in the table.  The upside to doing this join is that you'll be greatly reducing the amount of redundancy in the database.  If Honda gets bought, it will be easier to update its name, and your database will need less storage.

So this example (`make=Honda`) probably repeats itself with many of your other attributes.  From a pure theory perspective, it's best to normalize your database, and minimize/eliminate redundancy whenever possible.   From a practical perspective, your queries have to run well, and have to be reasonable to write in the first place.  So the right answer for most people is to balance these two perspectives with knowledge of how your query load works.

**Good Default Suggestion**

As a basic suggestion, consult those normalization materials; I'd recommend 3NF (third normal form) as a default baseline for most things that you do, but with the caveat that you can compromise off of this and normalize even more (or less) depending on the use case and query load.   In general, you'll find that heavily denormalized tables (where you're not doing joins, everything in one table) will perform better for large queries (assuming a good indexing strategy)

**Performance Testing**

In general, I wouldn't do it unless you have really hardcore reasons why you need utmost performance.   There's that old quote "premature optimization is at the root of all evil" and it applies to databases as well.  To do performance testing honestly, you have to get a lot of things right, and make sure many aspects of the DB are tuned correctly.  Setting up this experiment to get good data is not simple, and most people find that until the database gets really huge, they don't need to do this anyway.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! I think the core value you're identifying here is whether or not the metadata is likely to be highly repetitive and whether it has sets that change. For example: make=Honda is highly repetitive, but something like mileage=98123 would be unique to each record, therefore it can't really be further normalized. Does that sound like the right way to think of it?

Comment: Yes; this idea of repetitive also gets called "functional dependency" in the writing on normalization. There's a dependency between make and model for example. Honda makes the civic; so whenever model=Civic, you know make=Honda, and never make=Toyota.  This creates a dependency between make and model, which is a source of that redundancy.  Read the first link I posted, it contains a lot more info on these topics.